# ExecuteSQLCommand changed boolean value from False to NULL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have this WebInvoke method:

```
  <OperationContract()>
  <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
  Public Function Actions_Update_ByID(ByVal aID As Int32, Optional aActionID As Int32 = Nothing, Optional aConsequence_Paid As Boolean = Nothing, Optional aDate As DateTime = Nothing, Optional aName As String = Nothing, Optional aNotes As String = Nothing, Optional aReward_Paid As Boolean = Nothing) As String
    Try
      Dim c As New Common
      Dim ps As SqlParameter() = {New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int), New SqlParameter("@ActionID", SqlDbType.Int), New SqlParameter("@Consequence_Paid", SqlDbType.Bit), New SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime), New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar), New SqlParameter("@Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar), New SqlParameter("@Reward_Paid", SqlDbType.Bit)}
      ps(0).Value = aID
      ps(1).Value = IIf(aActionID = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aActionID)
      ps(2).Value = IIf(aConsequence_Paid = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aConsequence_Paid)
      ps(3).Value = IIf(aDate = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aDate)
      ps(4).Value = IIf(aName = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aName)
      ps(5).Value = IIf(aNotes = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aNotes)
      ps(6).Value = IIf(aReward_Paid = Nothing, DBNull.Value, aReward_Paid)
      c.ExecuteSQLCommand("UPDATE [Actions] SET [ActionID] = @ActionID,[Consequence_Paid] = @Consequence_Paid,[Date] = @Date,[Name] = @Name,[Notes] = @Notes,[Reward_Paid] = @Reward_Paid WHERE [ID] = @ID", ps)
      Return (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(String.Empty)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Dim row As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"error", ex.Message}}
      Return (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(row)
    End Try
  End Function
```

All parameters are passed to this method, trace of sql query is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Actions] SET [ActionID] = @ActionID,[Consequence_Paid] = @Consequence_Paid,[Date] = @Date,[Name] = @Name,[Notes] = @Notes,[Reward_Paid] = @Reward_Paid WHERE [ID] = @ID',N'@ID int,@ActionID int,@Consequence_Paid bit,@Date datetime,@Name nvarchar(9),@Notes nvarchar(30),@Reward_Paid bit',@ID=1,@ActionID=1258,@Consequence_Paid=NULL,@Date='2017-10-31 19:05:36',@Name=N'Dom C123 ',@Notes=N'Always Wear your licensesasasa',@Reward_Paid=NULL
```

ExecuteSQLCommand here:

```
  Sub ExecuteSQLCommand(ByVal commandText As String, ByVal params As SqlParameter())
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
    Try
      con.Open()

      Dim com As New SqlCommand(commandText, con)
      If Not params Is Nothing Then
        If params.Count > 0 Then
          com.Parameters.AddRange(params)
        End If
      End If
      com.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Finally
      If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
      End If
    End Try
  End Sub
```

So, every time I send False to Boolean arguments (aConsequence_Paid, aReward_Paid) I get Null value in database, how?

Thanks,
Dejan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The default value for the optional, primitive parameters can never be `Nothing`.  By specifying `Nothing`, any parameter not provided will default to their respective default value, so `aConsequence_Paid` will be false.
2. The `Iif` comparison will be a falsey comparison so that `false = Nothing` will evaluate to true.
3. So if no value is provided, or false is provided, then DbNull will be passed to the query.

I would recommend using Nullable types.

```
Public Function Actions_Update_ByID(Optional aConsequence_Paid = As Boolean? = Nothing)
  ' ...
  ps(2).Value = IIf(aConsequence_Paid.HasValue, aConsequence_Paid.Value, DBNull.Value)
  ' ...
End Function
```